# Fixed effects model nonsense result in R

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

im trying to create a simple fixed effects model of the impact minimum wages has on youth unemployment rate in europe but keep getting nonsense results. I have a panel data of 19 european countries from 2006-2020 and using the variables:

The data i'm interested in is:

`yemp20` - Which is the employment rate (%) of european youth between 20-24

`minwage` - Which is the lagged minimum wage to average wage ratio (kaitz index, and lagged meaning 2019 minwages are put into 2020).

My code (and for the  robust standard errors) and results are:

```
model <- plm( yemp20 ~ minwage + country + year,
                  index = c("country","year"),
                  model = "within", 
                  effect = "twoways",
                  data = data)

robols_se <- list(sqrt(diag(vcovHC(model, type = "HC1")))) 

                       yemp20           

minwage                17.197         
                      (15.586)          

Observations             274            
R2                      0.015           
Adjusted R2            -0.121           
F Statistic     3.635* (df = 1; 240)
```

which is just nonsense. What am i doing wrong? This should be very simple.

[image]
[image][image][image]

Comment: Welcome. Is the error stemming from fitting the model, or is it when you try and extract the standard errors? Also, can we see a small subset of your data?

Comment: Excuse me. When you said “errors” before I thought you were referring to error messages. Now that the output is more readable, what about it is nonsense?

Comment: Hello Thomas, I had trouble copying in the errors in right place which is why i wrote errors, but it looks right now. Anyway, the result just doesn't make sense. According to it, a rise in the minimum wage ratio would cause employment to go up with 17 %? And not just that, the sign should be negative and low with decimals according to theory regarding minimum wages and employment rate and earlier studies.

Comment: So many things could be awry, or maybe nothing is. First, shouldn’t `model` replace `olsmodel1`? Second, did you lag `minwage` yourself before running the model? Could we see a small subset of the data?

Comment: Sorry, i did the same test in 2 r script, but the numbers are right just that the model had another name. I lagged the minimumwage myself in excel by example putting 2019 minwages into 2020. I have now put in the small subset of data

Comment: You do not control for any other factor but individual and time effects and your standard error is almost as large as your coefficient (at least this is my reading of your output)... Maybe you want to re-think the model you want to estimate.

Comment: I have other variables like recession, inflation, youth population etc. I continue to get nonsense results even when i include them. My coefficient for minwage should be in a small number of decimal but its not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this answer will suffice, but I will try and draw your attention to some potential issues.

To begin, I don't see any issues with your code other than efficiency concerns, but I could be wrong. I recommended some R code below to help with this explanation. For example, I do not recommend adjusting the time configuration on the minimum wage ratio (i.e., `minwage`) before loading it into R. Different software packages have different default behavior, so try executing all your code in R, if possible. Speaking of default behavior, typically when we lag a variable we lose a time period. Unless your example data hasn't been preprocessed in Excel, the data frame should show "NA" values in 2006 *within each country* (e.g., Belgium, Czechia, etc.). Again, the lag operator should respect the panel structure. Since the `dplyr` and `plm` packages tend to mask each other, I used `plm::lag(minwage, k = 1)` to remove any ambiguity. Note also how I dropped `country` and `year` as the model will 'sweep out' the country- and year-specific effects. The `plm()` function recognizes the redundancies and will drop them for you.

Moreover, I don't see any issues with manually extracting the standard errors and storing them into a list-like structure. To save some extra keystrokes, try the `coeftest()` function. The result is a neat coefficient matrix with columns containing the estimates, standard errors, test statistics, and $p$-values. The results should be equivalent.

*Suggested Code*

```
# library(plm)
# library(lmtest)

model <- plm(yemp20 ~ plm::lag(minwage, k = 1), index = c("country", "year"), model = "within", effect = "twoways", data = data)
coeftest(model, vcov. = vcovHC(model , type = "HC1"))
```

*Other Considerations*

The model only considers the effect of lagged wages on unemployment, *ignoring all other variables*. Omitting other relevant covariates (e.g., eligible working age population) will bias your estimate.

Further, the large standard error suggests the estimate is likely to be on either side of zero. Even in the face of elevated uncertainty, you're making statements about the direction and magnitude of the relationship. Don't do this. The low $R^{2}$ also suggests a poor fit.

Lastly, I wouldn't recommend selecting a model to support your *a prior* assumptions about the effects of raising the minimum wage. The model, as specified, should have been considered *before* starting the analysis. Given your comments, it appears you've embarked on a scientific journey with the results already predetermined. Either live with the results, or rerun your experiment using new data. I worry you might try running endless strings of models until your confidence interval is completely to the left of zero.

Comment: A big thanks for taking the time to give a through explanation. The issue was as you said, me expecting I would get results that makes sense with just one variable included. I have adjusted that issue and included more relevant variables. One thing that I'm still wondering though is about the lagged value. If I lag my minimumwage in R then I will lose values for 2006 but If I lag them manually then I can put in 2005 values in 2006 and not have any NA in 2006. Is this ok? Because it seems logical to me.

Comment: Also you were right that I already had a predetermined answer in mind based on economic theory which just creates bias considering that the effects of minimum wage on employment is still a controversial topic among economists. Its something I will have to be careful to not repeat going into the future.

Comment: Losing time periods is a natural consequence of lagging your variables. Manually inserting the minimum wage in 2005 seems logical to me, but then I'm wondering why you excluded observations before 2006 in the first place. Don't discard data unnecessarily.

Comment: The reason I discarded studying previous year than 2006 is because of lack of data for all of the dependent variable before 2006. R seems to start regressing the fixed effect model from the latest year you have data from (for a variable) and discard all the previous years.